# data-frame melting issue and bubble plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataframe

```
a <- dput(df)
structure(list(Category = c("KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", 
"KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", 
"KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", 
"KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", "KEGG Pathway", 
"KEGG Pathway", "Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets", 
"Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets", 
"Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets", 
"Reactome Gene Sets", "Reactome Gene Sets"), Description = c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction", 
"Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction", "Salmonella infection", 
"Rheumatoid arthritis", "Salmonella infection", "Rheumatoid arthritis", 
"Toll-like receptor signaling pathway", "Toll-like receptor signaling pathway", 
"Chemokine signaling pathway", "Chemokine signaling pathway", 
"PI3K-Akt signaling pathway", "PI3K-Akt signaling pathway", "Rap1 signaling pathway", 
"Rap1 signaling pathway", "TNF signaling pathway", "TNF signaling pathway", 
"Interleukin-10 signaling", "Cytokine Signaling in Immune system", 
"Chemokine receptors bind chemokines", "Signaling by GPCR", "Signaling by Interleukins", 
"Peptide ligand-binding receptors", "GPCR ligand binding", "GPCR downstream signalling", 
"Class A/1 (Rhodopsin-like receptors)", "Signaling by Receptor Tyrosine Kinases", 
"Metabolism of nucleotides"), LogP = c(-6.6272284368, -6.6272284368, 
-2.9316614282, -2.8584315312, -2.7718494704, -2.7061868255, -2.6281915791, 
-2.6281915791, -2.5273777647, -2.5273777647, -3.6762135505, -3.2880356369, 
-2.2646576514, -2.117278626, -3.5410827773, -3.4151337331, -8.2548924333, 
-6.5328526991, -4.7978866035, -3.9736787567, -3.7112985062, -3.1255339841, 
-3.0317801957, -2.6859542446, -2.6603292838, -3.2998550411, -2.690237169
)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5642e14a3420>)
```

This is like this

```
head(a)
       Category                            Description      LogP
1: KEGG Pathway Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction -6.627228
2: KEGG Pathway Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction -6.627228
3: KEGG Pathway                   Salmonella infection -2.931661
4: KEGG Pathway                   Rheumatoid arthritis -2.858432
5: KEGG Pathway                   Salmonella infection -2.771849
6: KEGG Pathway                   Rheumatoid arthritis -2.706187
```

So i have two unique group in this Category column
KEGG and Reactome.

So I tried to melt to long format like this

```
pcm = melt(df, id = c("Description"))

pcm$Description <- factor(pcm$Description,levels=unique(pcm$Description))

colours = c( "#A54657",  "#582630", "#F7EE7F", "#4DAA57","#F1A66A","#F26157", "#F9ECCC", "#679289", "#33658A",
             "#F6AE2D","#86BBD8")


xx = ggplot(pcm, aes(x = variable, y = Description)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = value, fill = variable), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
  #scale_size_continuous(limits = c(-6, -1), range = c(1,17), breaks = c(1,10,50,75)) + 
  labs( x= "", y = "", size = "p value (%)", fill = "")  + 
  theme(legend.key=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold", angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 11), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2), 
        legend.position = "right") +  
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, guide = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(pcm$Description))) 

xx
```

[image: Plot like this]

But this I'm messing up something

What i require is in my x axis I want only my two categories and on my y axis Description labelled im not sure if two legends for pvalue can go inside.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

**UPDATED**

```
d <- unique_GO %>% group_by(Category) %>% slice_min(order_by = LogP, n = 10)




df$Description <- factor(d$Description,levels=unique(df$Description))

colours = c( "#A54657",  "#582630", "#F7EE7F", "#4DAA57","#F1A66A","#F26157", "#F9ECCC", "#679289", "#33658A",
             "#F6AE2D","#86BBD8")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Description)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = LogP, fill = Category), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$Description)))
```

[image: your first code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data in `a` was already in the long format ggplot works well with.

```
a$Description <- factor(a$Description,levels=unique(a$Description))

colours = c( "#A54657",  "#582630", "#F7EE7F", "#4DAA57","#F1A66A","#F26157", "#F9ECCC", "#679289", "#33658A",
             "#F6AE2D","#86BBD8")

ggplot(a, aes(x = Category, y = Description)) + 
   geom_point(aes(size = LogP, fill = Category), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
   ...
   scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(a$Description)))
```

[image]

---

EDIT

Lots of ways to fiddle with the text spacing. Here's one approach that uses the white space:

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
ggplot(a, aes(x = Category, y = Description)) + 
   geom_point(aes(size = LogP, fill = Category), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
   #scale_size_continuous(limits = c(-6, -1), range = c(1,17), breaks = c(1,10,50,75)) + 
   geom_text(data = a %>% filter(Category != "KEGG Pathway"),
             aes(label = Description), hjust = 1, nudge_x = -0.1) +
   geom_text(data = a %>% filter(Category == "KEGG Pathway"),
             aes(label = Description), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.1) +
   coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
   
   labs( x= "", y = "", size = "p value (%)", fill = "")  + 
   theme(legend.key=element_blank(), 
         
         axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold", angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1), 
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
         legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), 
         panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2), 
         legend.position = "right") +  
   scale_fill_manual(values = colours, guide = FALSE) + 
   scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(a$Description)))
```

[image]

Comment: wow straight forward solution ....instead of labeling it in y axis is it possible to label them like using ggrepel such as labeling each bubble individually ?

Comment: " fiddle with the text spacing"  i  lack the knowledge to play around this